# Error al iniciar httpd en centOS 7

Tags: apache, shell, httpd, centos

Recibo un error al iniciar httpd en centOS 7. He probado a reiniciar con

```
systemctl restart httpd.service
```

y también

```
systemctl start httpd.service
```

y me sigue apareciendo el mismo error, lo he hecho como usuario root. Cabe mencionar que antes funcionaba bien.

Aquí dejo una captura de pantalla de lo que he intentado y el error que recibo:
[image: status del servicio]

Comment: El usuario con que estás corriendo el comando es root?

Comment: No, era un usuario normal, pero ya lo hago con root, y ya todo está funcionando bien.

Answer (score 2):

Te esta notificando que no se puede unir al puerto 80, debe haber otro servicio que lo esta utilizando, puedes mirarlo utilizando el comando como root **netstat -putona**(si, así), te mostrara las conexiones establecidas, en espera, perdidas, y por cual puerto se comunican.

Si el servicio que esta escuchando por ahí es indispensable, pues cambia el puerto de escucha de Apache, el viene configurado para escuchar en el puerto 80(como ya sabrás).

Ademas puedes mostrar el log entero, ya que ese es un resumen de log, la respuesta de *Dannis Isaias* te menciona como hacerlo.

Answer (score 1):

Tal como te indica:

```
Unable to open logs
```

no tiene los permisos de escritura/lectura y lo más seguro tampoco de usar el puerto 80

Corre tu comando con sudo

```
sudo systemctl restart httpd
```

Answer (score 1):

Hola por lo que leo al inicio del mensaje es que el **puerto 80 está siendo ocupado** por otro proceso o servicio. Revisa que proceso o servicio está utilizando el puerto.

Puedes cambiar también el puerto de del HTTPD en sus configuraciones.

Answer (score -1):

revisar el archivo /var/log/httpd/error_log

ahi puedes encontrar cualquier error de configuración que impida el funcionamiento del servicio

o puedes usar el comando: service httpd status

Espero te sirva

Comment: Esta información, al ser más una sugerencia o recomendación que una respuesta concreta que resuelve el problema, sería mejor anotarlo como comentario en la respuesta (en cuanto alcances la reputación que te permita la posibilidad de escribir comentarios)